# Tracking code doesn't work

Tags: google-analytics

I was trying to put the GA tracking code on my web site using PHP, placing it before the closing head tag.

```
<?php include_once("analyticstracking.php") ?>
```

The script is shown in the correct place and everything should be ok and it should start collecting data, but for some unknown reason I see the following status message on my admin page...

> On the home page of your site has been detected Google Analytics tracking code. In order for Analytics to function properly, it is necessary, you or the site administrator add this code to each page of your site.

Comment: Have you placed the code on all your pages via your template page?

Comment: It can take some time for the message to disappear. Have you checked to see if a request to Google Analytics is made on the page (via developer tools or a proxy debugger)?

Comment: I have already solved my problem. You have to just give it some time (in next few days it was working properly). Anyway thanks for your answers.